# Incorrect number of dimensions when using geosphere package in R

Tags: r, geospatial, geosphere

Trying to calculate the distance matrix between lat/long points in  two datasets.... 
This is my R script code and then the error message. Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

```
> library(geosphere)
## step 1: open 2000 data for birds and air temp
> birds<-read.table(file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t")
> birds
> temp<-read.table(file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t")
> temp

##step 2: calculate the distance matrix D, which is the distance between lat/long points in your two datasets

> D = distm (birds<- 3:2, temp<- 2:1)
> new_birds =cbind(birds, temp[apply(D , 1 , which.min),])
```

> Error in temp[apply(D, 1, which.min), ] : incorrect number of
>   dimensions

Comment: Can you include the code to create temp and D, or at least the output of dim(temp) class(temp) dim(D) class(D)?

Comment: Appears that temp is not a two dimensional object.

Comment: Thanks, @mdsumner and 42- 
I have edited the question to include the code. Is that what you meant?

Comment: do you mean to use `birds <- 3:2` or `birds[, 3:2]`, ie third and second column of birds. `birds <- 3:2` will assign the values 3 and 2 to birds